# How to prevent an error to occur in a script appended in chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, developer-console

I have a script which I want to run it throw the console of developer tools.

The script is a fetch to an url: [www.not-my-website.com/page-1/](http://www.not-my-website.com/page-1/)

Further, the [www.not-my-website.com/page-1/](http://www.not-my-website.com/page-1/) redirects to [www.not-my-website.com/page-2/](http://www.not-my-website.com/page-2/)

[www.not-my-website.com/page-2/](http://www.not-my-website.com/page-2/) redirects to [www.not-my-website.com/page-3/](http://www.not-my-website.com/page-3/)

....

[www.not-my-website.com/page-99/](http://www.not-my-website.com/page-99/) redirects to [www.not-my-website.com/page-100/](http://www.not-my-website.com/page-100/)

And the error I get in the console is `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS 302`.

That's because there are to many redirects made by the fetched url.

So, I need a way to prevent this behavior.

I want the script to be run and to prevent stopping the script to run.

I try to create a snippet and to set the debugger to ignore it. But the script still throws the `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` 302 error.

So, how can I prevent this behavior ?

I just want to run the script and not to be stopped because there are to many redirects. I want to run it. It has an end. On [www.not-my-website.com/page-100/](http://www.not-my-website.com/page-100/).

Attached a print of what I made and is not working. Some help ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome has a redirect limit of `20`, and which can't be modified.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. I think the other way may be to modify chromium...

Comment: Yes, also you can mark it as the answer so others can find it useful.